# Error in truth table in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

[Truth table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucIO0.jpg)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmukW.jpg)

I calculated Karnaugh map but my code is not correct. I am getting error: "Error for D='1' C='0' B='1' A='0'expected O='1', recieved O='0'".

Where I am making mistake?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
entity truth_table is port(   A,B,C,D : in    std_logic;
                              O       : out   std_logic);
end truth_table;  

architecture behavior of truth_table isbegin

O <= (((not A) and C and D) or ((not D) and B and C) or (A and (not C) and D) or (A and C and (not B)));
end behavior;
```

Comment: You should avoid to post code as linked image. Code can nicely be shown as text inside your question.

Comment: If your code does not replicate the truth table, it's because you made an error in your K-map. You haven't shown this, so we cannot tell what you did wrong! Personally I found this one easier working with the inverse output, then inverting the whole equation at the end. This gives 4 products to sum instead of 6.

Comment: My mistake, inverting doesn't give less products to sum, but it does use less gate inputs if that's important for the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical equation on the right of your signal 'O' is wrong it should be:

```
O <= (((not D) and B and A) or ((not A) and C and B) or (D and (not B) and A) or (D and B and (not C)));
```

See http://www.32x8.com/var4.html and try it yourself but note that the ordering of the columns is the opposite than in your truth table.

Comment: I used the same site, but I didn't realize that the order of columns are opposite and I was always getting the wrong result.

Comment: "not" has the highest operator priority here. You don't need the enclosing parens - e.g. `(not D)` can be expressed as `not D`. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.2 Operators, 9.2.1 General, the list of operators in increasing priority.